# Spring aop not working on programmatically registered bean

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

I have an `@Aspect` in my app that insercepts all `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` method calls. An it worked fine, while I had a single `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` bean.

But the requirement changed and now I have a multiple templates that are placed in a map.
First the map itself was a bean, but the elements (jdbcTemplates) - weren't so my aspect stopped working.

I tried to register each tempalte as a bean and added them to a map, but with no result, the calls are not intercepted. Can I get the aspect working?

Code:
JDBC templates condig:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> namedParameterJdbcTemplates() {
    
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory =
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory();
    
    Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> templates = new HashedMap<>();
    
    dataSources().forEach((key, value) -> {
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(key, new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(value));

    templates.put(key, (NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) beanFactory.getBean(key));
            });
    
    return templates;
        }
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JdbcTemplateContextAspect {

    private NotificationService telegram;

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.*(String, ..))")
    public void sqlQuery() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.*(String, ..))")
    public void sqlNamedParamQuery() {
    }

    @Around("sqlQuery() || sqlNamedParamQuery()")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: `HashedMap` seems to be a typo ? If this is not the actual code , a complete reproducible example would help others to help you better .  Please share the code which invokes the beans to be advised as well.

Comment: I agree with R.G. I am also wondering where you get the application context from while auto-wiring the application. Usually the application context is being returned after the wiring is finished, AFAIK. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub.

Comment: @R.G Even if this is a type it doesn't affect the desired behaviour

Comment: @FrankieDrake when the code shared itself is incorrect , from my experience here , the issue would be something else . It would be a waste of time for anyone trying to help you. Good that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the soultion is quite easy, just inject `GenericWebApplicationContext` and `applicationContext.registerBean`...

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataSourcesConfig {

    private final GenericWebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSources() {

        //gathering datasources
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> namedParameterJdbcTemplates() {

        Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> templates = new HashMap<>();

        dataSources().forEach((key, value) -> {
            applicationContext.registerBean(key, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class,
                    () -> new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(value));
            templates.put(key, applicationContext.getBean(key, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class));
        });


        return templates;
    }
}
```